# How long does it take for Epic Projects to show up?

Tags: simcity-buildit

I bought the department of special projects a few days ago and still no epic projects have shown up, am I missing something? Is there other requirements to start building epic projects?

Comment: Have you built the Department of Epic Projects? You will need that before you get any projects. You'll see a winged helmet icon over a building when it's ready. The first one (for me) started right away, after you complete your first, it takes about 12 hours before you get another one.

Comment: Yes I have built the department of epic projects when the update came out and im level 46. Still no winged helmet icons have shown up.

Comment: Looks like you also have to have specialty areas... so for example, you may get an education epic project in a zone near a school. So make sure you've got residential buildings near speciality areas.

Comment: Also, the project tasks come from the specialization buildings themselves. So, if you get the education project, the more schools you have (particularly the more 3-star schools you have), the more tasks you can get. The number of stars indicates the number of points you get for each completed task.

Comment: I have all specialist education buildings surrounded by residential buildings. Not sure what else the problem might be.

Comment: Yeah, those are pretty much all the things I can think of. Try contacting their support people, I guess.

Comment: Yeah I think that's really my only option left. Thanks anyway!

Comment: how did this work out for you? Has it started working yet?

Answer (score 1):

You have to be Level 24 to unlock your first Epic Project. Tap on the building and it will say so.

Comment: I'm level 46 though

Answer (score 1):

You need to also have transportation, education, beach, mountain items because that is where you get the tasks to show up. For instance if you choose transportation, tasks will show only on bus station, balloon, helicopter pads etc.

Answer (score 0):

To start epic project. first you need Deptt of Epic Project. A regular residential building (not tokyo, london , paris or omega). that regular building must be close to one specialization building (Education, Gambling, Landmark etc)

Answer (score 0):

Epic projects appear after you have any specialisation apart from parks and landscape that benefits a fully upgraded residential zone. Once you have completed an epic project, there is a 12 hour cooldown until you can start another one. Start an epic project by taping on the winged gold helmet.

You can read more on EA's Help Pages: [Simcity Buildit Epic Projects](https://help.ea.com/en-us/help/simcity/simcity-buildit/simcity-buildit-epic-projects)

Answer (score 0):

Click the blue floating icon over government building. Once you clicked them all tap on epic projects building, then your projects will start.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but I solved it, the residential building has to be in the green affected area of a building. I had moved my mountain buildings away from my residential buildings because I couldn't see over them but you can't do that obviously.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had been ignoring the blue bubble over the TOWN HALL - the lady kept talking to me about “building a park” and seeing as I didn’t want to build a park, I never passed that message. Once I did build a park at lvl 30, the next town hall message came through, then the next, etc. After a few more messages about the airport and Vu’s tower, the message to create your first epic building shows up.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with seasonal items like “Santa’s workshop” and EP. Until I boxed it up and removed it EP’s never spawned for me and I was level 28. I had every service, beach and mountains opened. The second I removed the workshop I got an epic project.